# Is it possible to use Tab-only intellisense completion as the default for all files in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, intellisense

By default, Visual Studio 2019 Intellisense uses **automatic completion** instead of **Tab-only completion** for all files. On a per file basis, you can "Switch between automatic and tab-only Intellisense completion" using the *Edit->Intellisense->...* menu option, the toolbar button, and the shortcut *Ctrl+Alt+Space*.

I prefer the tab-only completion for all files, and would prefer not having to check the state of this setting for each file every time it is opened -- or forget to check and be surprised when some code is "magically" deleted while I'm typing and replaced with something else.

In the end, I just want to **set a default state** of the "Intellisense completion" setting **to be tab-only completion** for all files, or for the whole IDE.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try to set this:  In Visual Studio > Tools > Options > Text Editor > Advanced > Default IntelliSense completion mode, change from `Automatic` to `Tab-only`.

[image]

Comment: That was it exactly. I'm as blind as a bat, even after seeing your answer I couldn't see the option as my eyes scanned up and down that settings page.

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer Tianyu!

I also had trouble finding it even after it was pointed out @JayTennant - these VS options menus really know how to make my eyes get tired