# Visual Studio 2022 (or earlier) disable autocomplete after typing a dot (.)

Tags: editor, intellisense, auto, disable

[image]

How can I disable, that after typing a dot (.) Visual Studio will automatically print FileStyleUriParser?
Don't get me wrong, I want the suggestions, but I don't want Visual Studio to automatically replace with the first suggestion in the list, because this is annoying and does not make any sense at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use Tab-only intellisense completion as the default for all files in Visual Studio 2019?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68837507/is-it-possible-to-use-tab-only-intellisense-completion-as-the-default-for-all-fi)

Answer (score 2):

"For your requirement, you can try to use the option to change the IntelliSense completion mode: Edit > IntelliSense > Switch between automatic and tab-only IntelliSense completion or shortcut: Ctrl+Alt+Space.

Or you can also set the IntelliSense completion mode to Tab-only: Tools > Options > Text Editor > Advanced > Default IntelliSense completion mode: > select Tab-only in the dropdown."

[Taken from  AnnaXiu's answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/760368/disabling-autocompletion-from-spacebar-in-vs-2022.html)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, with Visual Studio Professional 2022 this is not possible. You can either have  suggestions, or have auto-replace disabled, but you can't have both.

One option is to downgrade to Visual Studio 2019 or upgrade to another IDE such as Rider.

[image]